# shlokas mentioning Apauruṣeyā

Tags: vedas

Are there any shlokas mentioning the word Apauruṣeyā? i have tried to find a shloka written either in the Upanishads or in the Puranas mentioning the word apauruseya in Sanskrit but I am unable to.

Comment: Monier Williams mentions it is from the ṣaḍviṃśa brāhmaṇa. That's as far as I could go. If I get more info I'll answer.

Comment: yes the ṣaḍviṃśa brāhmaṇa does mention the term Apauruṣeyā but it uses it as an adjective for pain rather than for mantra.